# Should Parallel.ForEach be used in DB calls?

Tags: parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

I've got a list of Foo IDs. I need to call a stored procedure for each ID.

e.g.

```
Guid[] siteIds = ...; // typically contains 100 to 300 elements
foreach (var id in siteIds)
{
   db.MySproc(id); // Executes some stored procedure.
}
```

Each call is pretty independent of the other rows, this shouldn't be contentious in the database.

My question: **would it be beneficial to parallelize this using Parallel.ForEach**? Or is database IO going to be a bottleneck, and more threads would just result in more contention?

I would measure it myself, however, it's difficult to measure this on my test environment where the data and load is much smaller than our real web server.

Comment: I would recommend you measuring the performances of both approaches and picking the faster one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out of curiosity, why do you want to optmize it with *Parallel.ForEach* and spawn threads / open connections / pass data / get response for **every item** instead of writing a simple "sproc" that will work with list of IDs instead of single ID?

From the first look, it should get you a lot more noticable improvement.

Comment: Answer: it's complicated. I'm working on an old system, my hands are kind of ties. Additionally, it's not as clear-cut as it might seem; I'm actually calling a .NET method that does some crap, then some more crap, then calls a sproc. Ripping this out of this old system would be dangerous.

Answer (score 1):

I would think that the Parallel.ForEach would work, assuming that your DB server can handle the ~150-300 concurrent operations.

The only way to know for sure is to measure both.

Comment: I'm sure SQL can handle lots of concurrent tasks, given connection pooling and all that, but the part I'm unsure about is whether the resulting IO contention will cancel out.